# Citation formatting

Tags: bibtex

I'm not sure how to fix my citation output - BibTex is generating a citation that, when rendered, looks like:

Brain and Cognition, 55(1):30 - 40, 2004. <‍ce:title>Development of Orbitofrontal Func- tion<‍/ce:title>.

How can I get rid of the "ce:title" tags? The referenced .bib file is

```
@article{Bechara200430,
title = "The role of emotion in decision-making: Evidence from neurological patients with orbitofrontal damage ",
journal = "Brain and Cognition ",
volume = "55",
number = "1",
pages = "30 - 40",
year = "2004",
note = "<ce:title>Development of Orbitofrontal Function</ce:title> ",
issn = "0278-2626",
doi = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.bandc.2003.04.001",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0278262603002859",
author = "Antoine Bechara"
}
```

Here is a sample document:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

This is the misformatted citation \cite{Bechara200430}\\

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{oberdiek-bundle,/Users/Kevin/Downloads/science}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. This is surely unusual, so without an example it's really difficult to say something.

Comment: Done - and I linked the referenced .bib file. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Remove the tags from the `note` field. Do you need them?

Comment: Great- that fixed it for me; sorry – still feeling my way around BibTex, but just discovered JabRef, which is quite useful. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The contents of the `note` field is typeset “as is”. One might think of adding LaTeX code that gets rid of those tags, but such code would be rather fragile, because `<` or `>` might be legitimate in some entry, say in a title with a math formula or a note itself.

It's much easier to check the `.bib` file for their presence and zap them by hand.